# Android Json parsing first three value

Tags: android

The Json ::

{"userinfo":[{"id":"4","name":"Md Abu Hasan Masud","email":"abuhasanmasud@gmail.com","image":"54c0952d7c7500.607043061421907245.jpg","imgLink":"http://dbtel.net/contactmanager/uploads/54c0952d7c7500.607043061421907245.jpg","imgthumbLink":"http://dbtel.net/contactmanager/uploads/thumbs/54c0952d7c7500.607043061421907245.jpg","mobile_number":"01722761395","phone_number":"01711107287","designation":"Software Engineer","department":"Business Development","concern":"DBL Telecom Ltd"}]}

**This is the json. when i want to parse it through some string variable I only get first three variable value other get null.**

Code :

```
{
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
       String jsonSt = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
         Log.e("Json String===", ""+jsonSt);

        if (jsonSt != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonSt);
                jSongArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_EMPLOYEE);



                   JSONObject oneObject = jSongArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    sName = oneObject.getString(TAG_EMPLOYEE_NAME);
                    sDesignation = oneObject.getString(TAG_DESIGNATION);
                    sDepartment = oneObject.getString(TAG_DEPARTMENT);
                    sJoinDate = oneObject.getString(TAG_JOIN_DATE);
                    sImagePath = oneObject.getString(TAG_IMAGE_PATH);
                    sEmail = oneObject.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    sMobileNumber = oneObject.getString(TAG_MOBILE_NUMBER);
                    sPhoneNumber = oneObject.getString(TAG_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    sConcern=oneObject.getString(TAG_CONCERN);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here I get Name, Designation and Department but I am getting other null. Its an odd problem I think. When I put other variable in the front the other three getting value . This three getting null. 
Actually In a word only the first three variable getting the value. Other getting null.

Comment: also show keys which you are using for retrieving values from JSONObject

Comment: there is no problem with the keys. First three always get value .

Comment: private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEE = "userinfo";
    private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEE_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DESIGNATION = "designation";
    private static final String TAG_JOIN_DATE = "join_date";
    private static final String TAG_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_number";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE_PATH = "imgthumbLink";
    private static final String TAG_DEPARTMENT = "department";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
sJoinDate = oneObject.getString(TAG_JOIN_DATE);
```

This line causing issue because not key available in provided JSON string with `join_date`. so next line not executing and control is going in catch block because if key is not available then `getString` will through `JSONException` exception.

To fix this issue use [JSONObject.optString](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29) which will return `null` is provided key not found in `JSONObject`.